# Why is horizontal scroll on flexbox hiding elements to the left?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I have a flexbox container with scrolling along the x axis. It scrolls properly, but for some reason, many items within the container are hidden to the left of the screen, outside of the display. I have no idea why and am looking to make it such that the first element in the list is the first element seen in the leftmost box of the flexbox.

```
.home-carousel-cards {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
overflow-x: auto;
flex-shrink: 0;
margin: 0 -1px;
justify-content: center;
}

.home-item-card {
    width: 241px;
    min-width: 220px;
    height: 300px;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0 1px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

The result:
[image]

The blue highlighted div is the first visible element. As you can see, the first shoe actually seen is certainly not the first element in the list, and all of the previous elements are not visible. I want the user to scroll right to the end of the list but can't get past this.

Comment: why do you have a `margin: 0 -1px;`. maybe that's pushing the elements to the left?

Comment: Use `outline` instead of border: `border: 1px solid black;` . The line will appears. However it might create other issues, that I let you discover...

Comment: Could you put up a working snippet, enough HTML so that we can see the problem for ourselves. The items in the flex are centered is possibly the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is because `justify-center` might not be the way to go to for this

You should

- remove "justify-content: center"
- use "margin-left: auto" on the first element
- use "margin-right: auto" on the last element

[Image to show differences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apZRr.gif)

I wrote a whole article on this https://dev.to/martinratinaud/centering-flex-items-with-overflow-40j0

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I did fix it with

display="-webkit-inline-box" try this solution